# Send iOS Push notification in php with .p8 file

Tags: php, ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Apple has updated their push notification service and the certificate file received is now a .p8 file. There are many examples online of how to send a push notification with the .pem file but I can't find anything for a .p8 file. Does anyone have any code that works with the .p8 file?

Answer (score 20):

With the script below I'm able to send token-based push notifications with the .p8 file.

The minimum version of curl supporting this is 7.38.0, and it must be compiled with the flag --with-nghttp2 and openssl >= 1.0.2

```
<?php

  $keyfile = 'AuthKey_AABBCC1234.p8';               # <- Your AuthKey file
  $keyid = 'AABBCC1234';                            # <- Your Key ID
  $teamid = 'AB12CD34EF';                           # <- Your Team ID (see Developer Portal)
  $bundleid = 'com.company.YourApp';                # <- Your Bundle ID
  $url = 'https://api.development.push.apple.com';  # <- development url, or use http://api.push.apple.com for production environment
  $token = 'e2c48ed32ef9b018........';              # <- Device Token

  $message = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hi there!","sound":"default"}}';

  $key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.$keyfile);

  $header = ['alg'=>'ES256','kid'=>$keyid];
  $claims = ['iss'=>$teamid,'iat'=>time()];

  $header_encoded = base64($header);
  $claims_encoded = base64($claims);

  $signature = '';
  openssl_sign($header_encoded . '.' . $claims_encoded, $signature, $key, 'sha256');
  $jwt = $header_encoded . '.' . $claims_encoded . '.' . base64_encode($signature);

  // only needed for PHP prior to 5.5.24
  if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
      define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
  }

  $http2ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($http2ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
    CURLOPT_URL => "$url/3/device/$token",
    CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "apns-topic: {$bundleid}",
      "authorization: bearer $jwt"
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
  ));

  $result = curl_exec($http2ch);
  if ($result === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception("Curl failed: ".curl_error($http2ch));
  }

  $status = curl_getinfo($http2ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  echo $status;

  function base64($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(json_encode($data)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
  }

?>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error as 'Unexpected HTTP/1.x request: POST /3/device/5cba9501b6b6b3d6xxxxxxxxxxxxx'. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Can you try to restart the webserver as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48007808/1833495 ?

Comment: I was getting this error when i tried to run the above code ' Curl failed: No URL set!' even though am passing the url. so i just replaced the `curl_setopt_array` to `curl_setopt` and it worked for me.

Comment: @Hareesh I managed to solve this issue, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55147621/3210941

Comment: @RoelKoops Could you tell me how we can generate apple developer token for musickit apis

Comment: @RoelKoops what should we pass in $signature parameter?

Comment: @JaySojitra: You don't have to fill $signature yourself. This will be done by openssl_sign when the call is succesfull, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php

Comment: I only have access to curl version 7.29.0. Is there any way to run this with this version?

Comment: @Chris: I don't think so, curl 7.29.0 is missing HTTP/2 support

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled to find a simple library to send APNS notifications with a .p8 file in PHP. I found the [edamov/pushok](https://github.com/edamov/pushok) library to be the most straightforward and object-oriented. Just install the package with `composer require edamov/pushok` and follow the instructions in [Getting Started](https://github.com/edamov/pushok#getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to send push notification with new [JWT based push notification service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1) using PHP. Its was definitely not a easy task.

I have uploaded project on [GitHub](https://github.com/jaypatel28/php-jwt-pushnotification). You can download from there and  make sure you replace your .p8 file with existing .p8 file.

Then in `push.php` file you need to replace your `kid`, `iss(Team ID)`, `token` and `app_bundle_id`.

Go to the directory and from terminal run the command `php push.php`. If everything goes well then you should receive push notification.

This solution works well for me. Just make sure that you don't get any errors in terminal.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have try but not work in php5.6 version give error.

Comment: @Jay can you explain how can i use it n laravel