# Send Push with .p8 and PHP

Tags: php, openssl, apple-push-notifications, p8

I need to send Push notifications through PHP script by using .p8 file and found following code in similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628335/send-ios-push-notification-in-php-with-p8-file).

```
<?php

  $keyfile = 'AuthKey_AABBCC1234.p8';               # <- Your AuthKey file
  $keyid = 'AABBCC1234';                            # <- Your Key ID
  $teamid = 'AB12CD34EF';                           # <- Your Team ID (see Developer Portal)
  $bundleid = 'com.company.YourApp';                # <- Your Bundle ID
  $url = 'https://api.development.push.apple.com';  # <- development url, or use http://api.push.apple.com for production environment
  $token = 'e2c48ed32ef9b018........';              # <- Device Token

  $message = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hi there!","sound":"default"}}';

  $key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.$keyfile);

  $header = ['alg'=>'ES256','kid'=>$keyid];
  $claims = ['iss'=>$teamid,'iat'=>time()];

  $header_encoded = base64($header);
  $claims_encoded = base64($claims);

  $signature = '';
  openssl_sign($header_encoded . '.' . $claims_encoded, $signature, $key, 'sha256');
  $jwt = $header_encoded . '.' . $claims_encoded . '.' . base64_encode($signature);

  // only needed for PHP prior to 5.5.24
  if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
      define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
  }

  $http2ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($http2ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
    CURLOPT_URL => "$url/3/device/$token",
    CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "apns-topic: {$bundleid}",
      "authorization: bearer $jwt"
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
  ));

  $result = curl_exec($http2ch);
  if ($result === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception("Curl failed: ".curl_error($http2ch));
  }

  $status = curl_getinfo($http2ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  echo $status;

  function base64($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(json_encode($data)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
  }

?>
```

However, I found that `openssl_pkey_get_private` doesn't read the key file and it gives following error when I debug it.

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.$keyfile);
if ($key === false) {
    var_dump(openssl_error_string());
}
```

error :

```
'error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory'
```

Please note that there is no issue with `curl` as `HTTP2` was enabled for the `curl` and I am using `PHP7`. In testing phase I'm using the script and file on the same folder to avoid any path issues.

Any clue where it went wrong ?

Comment: what's the contents of the $keyfile? can you physically open that file from your terminal? It appears it's not there, thus throwing the 'no such file or directory' error.

Comment: yes, I can open it. I place both php script and .p8 file in the same folder and didn't specify any path when given to the file://.

Comment: what OS are you using? unix based are case sensitive. I tried your code and it works fine:it throws string(50) "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line" instead of the file not found error

Comment: my bad, I didn't mention it. I am using wamp server on windows 10.

Comment: i tried replicating it using the browser instead, vs via terminal. If accessed via browser, you need to provide the absolute path. Something like this:  openssl_pkey_get_private('file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/'.$keyfile);

Comment: You should use full path.

Comment: I already tried that without success like bellow, __ DIR __ . '/AuthKey_G4JJ3X8ZZ7.p8'

Comment: @JanithChinthana, would you put your testing environment to your post? like version of OS, PHP, virtual env etc.

Comment: what if i want to send to multiple devices the same message, can i use an array of tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to next URL if did not read yet.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php

To narrow down your issue, please use *same directory for your php file and key file* and try this working code.

**Working code**

```
$keyfile="file://".__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."key.p8"; //absolute path
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($keyfile);

if ($key === false) {
    var_dump(openssl_error_string());
}else{
    var_dump($key);
}
```

The following might be an issue.

1. **Path**

Following path styles should work.

```
$keyfile="file:///home/john/php/key.p8"; // unix absoulute path
$keyfile="file://C:\\users\\john\\php\\key.p8"; // windows absoulute path
$keyfile="file://".__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."key.p8"; //absoulute path for unix, windows
$keyfile="file://key.p8"; // relative path, unix, windows, (php,key files in same directory)

$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($keyfile);
```

If path does not exist, error will be like

> "error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory"

2. **Web environment**

   Check your web root and web user access permission to the folder and key file.

   To reduce issues, test it on php build-in web server env rather than WAMP env.

```
>php -S localhost:80
```

3. **Corrupted key file**

saved as certain type which include whitespaces.
This can occur error like next.

> "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

```
in my case, key file was saved as UTF-8 with BOM(whitespaces)
```

**DEBUG key file 1 - READ FROM VARIABLE**

This code should work. I got key file from
http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/openssl_pkey_get_private

Please replace $str to yours.

```
$str = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIIEogIBAAKCAQEA0llCeBjy18RylTdBih9GMUSZIC3GzeN0vQ9W8E3nwy2jdeUn 
H3GBXWpMo3F43V68zM2Qz5epRNmlLSkY/PJUfJIC8Yc1VEokT52q87hH/XJ5eS8h 
eZnjuSlPAGi8oZ3ImVbruzV7XmlD+QsCSxJW7tBv0dqJ71e1gAAisCXK2m7iyf/u 
l6rT0Zz0ptYH4IZfwc/hQ9JcMg69uM+3bb4oBFsixMmEQwxKZsXk3YmO/YRjRbay 
+6+79bSV/frW+lWhknyGSIJp2CJArYcOdbK1bXx1dRWpbNSExo7dWwuPC0Y7a5AE 
eoZofieQPPBhXlp1hPgLYGat71pDqBjKLvF5GwIDAQABAoIBACPItYsSy3UzYT7L 
OKYTrfBBuD8GKpTqBfkHvAWDa1MD15P92Mr7l0NaCxGfAy29qSa6LdFy/oPM9tGY 
9TxKyV6rxD5sfwEI3+Z/bw6pIe4W5F1eTDaQnHHqehsatkRUQET9yXp+na8w/zRF 
0C0PQKS95tfvcpm59RGCdGQ8+aZw+cIy/xez75W8IS/hagMxe7xYPjpkOkSCCEJU 
zmbVq6AyWodASV0p4H9p8I+c0vO2hJ/ELJ167w6T+2/GlZg979rlyHoTW8jK2BbG 
IRGaPo+c2GANXa686tdpbkPd6oJliXwBSNolxmXShvlveBbPFAJJACzCmbXNj9kH 
6/K+SWkCgYEA7FNudcTkRPV8TzKhJ1AzDjw3VcnraYhY8IlNxbk7RVHLdkoUtwk/ 
mImeBlEfCoz9V+S/gRgeQ+1Vb/BCbS24+bN/+IGoNRFMRcOieFt6lQUpj7a9NeSo 
IEclGgUiU7QR3xH73SB4GC3rgSPeHJhJZC5EJq5TzYjXTPGPpBD3zicCgYEA49wz 
zfMDYIH8h4L65r/eJYIbLwpvgktgaYvhijO3qfZSWW+Y19jCBn55f65YOhPGQBHA 
my0f+tVxFNZ/OupbrAIIzogxlCIYHNBawDhoHN/sB3/lSBAjifySNLyRlA62oA0w 
wXvXVLVWMa3aXim3c9AlnLF1fHwcvwpOKSfdye0CgYBb1mBKq+T5V1yjek1d9bCh 
i40FbZ5qOG43q2Ppvn3mBk9G/KroJlPsdy5NziB9/SRGj8JL7I92Xjihc4Cc5PPJ 
NZQ5gklXtg0p30i39PTCDGuGScFlvCIJyRwF7JDWblezlE2INSH2Y4HtgX7DJfr/ 
T2t0jLJMYS0p3YWwgFeMaQKBgHUIe/8y6zAdc5QynSX5tGL1gXrW1FFK39k2RICU 
cag1YTSYkhuDNJzbRxJifORPlcsAkzngooVWLb+zMCQVjUI6xUU3RKe+Hz5lccc6 
8ZarGHL9qMkrqOVNudamZ+tw5zIrtDgcoIvcm8nmbrtgl94/MaJar2ph4O3qoByZ 
Ylw9AoGAIdS79s0VKkj4VVXqK47ZcI7jGL4V4C8ujU8YcMNV88xwCoDg9ZIFprWA 
P5p/cnvj6aHnqL58XiH0+bE0Lt3J+U6N6JelQQevgBHooMFh4FpDXcVda7xB3rK3 
woqbi8fNhr827H2maxIZPtVG95/mvR4k5z1Jrdnr34ZUmtC6U5Q= 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF;

$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($str);
if ($key === false) {
    var_dump(openssl_error_string());
}else{
    var_dump($key);
}
```

OUTPUT

> resource(4) of type (OpenSSL key)

**DEBUG key file 2 - READ FROM FILE**

copy your key strings($str) to key file like "key.p8".

```
$str = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
...YOUR KEY STINGS HERE...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF;

$str2 = file_get_contents("key.p8");

$len1 = strlen ($str);
$len2 = strlen ($str2);
if($len1 !== $len2) echo "File has been corrupted.";

$key = openssl_pkey_get_private($str2);

if ($key === false) {
    var_dump(openssl_error_string());
}else{
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This script can be used to send a push to IOS using .p8 certificate.
Make sure the location of the certificate is correct

````
<?php

      $keyfile = 'AuthKey_AABBCC1234.p8';               // Your p8 Key file
      $keyid = 'AABBCC1234';                            // Your Key ID
      $teamid = 'AB12CD34EF';                           // Your Team ID (see Developer Portal)
      $bundleid = 'com.company.YourApp';                // Your Bundle ID
      $url = 'https://api.development.push.apple.com';  // development url, or use http://api.push.apple.com for production environment
      $token = 'e2c48ed32ef9b018........';              // Device Token

      $message = '{"aps":{"alert":"Hi there!","sound":"default"}}';

      $key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://'.$keyfile);

      $header = ['alg'=>'ES256','kid'=>$keyid];
      $claims = ['iss'=>$teamid,'iat'=>time()];

      $header_encoded = base64($header);
      $claims_encoded = base64($claims);

      $signature = '';
      openssl_sign($header_encoded . '.' . $claims_encoded, $signature, $key, 'sha256');
      $jwt = $header_encoded . '.' . $claims_encoded . '.' . base64_encode($signature);

      // only needed for PHP prior to 5.5.24
      if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
          define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
      }

      $http2ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt_array($http2ch, array(
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
        CURLOPT_URL => "$url/3/device/$token",
        CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "apns-topic: {$bundleid}",
          "authorization: bearer $jwt"
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
      ));

      $result = curl_exec($http2ch);
      if ($result === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("Curl failed: ".curl_error($http2ch));
      }

      $status = curl_getinfo($http2ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      echo $status;

      function base64($data) {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(json_encode($data)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
      }

    ?>```
````

Comment: This is the exact same code in the question. Why is this upvoted?

Comment: what if i want to send to multiple devices the same message, can i use an array of tokens?